# Launching a Spark app using SparkLauncher from SparkStreaming app

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-launcher

I'm writing a KafkaConsumer application, where we run Kafka Consumer as Spark Streaming Application in Yarn-Cluster mode. The responsibility of this KafkaConsumer is to listen to different topics and launch new SparkApplications in Yarn-Cluster mode using org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher.

Now the issue is, new Spark Applications are getting launched successfully when KafkaConsumer is running in Yarn-Client mode, but in Cluster mode it is getting stuck.

Any help or pointers are highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its getting stuck? Please elaborate ! Are you experiencing some error ?

Comment: No error, but the applicationId of child process just got submitted and never changed to Running status